# how to get the output of sql query which is in sql file to shell script file from which we are executing the sql file

Tags: sql, linux, unix, awk

I have script file `getUserDetails.sh` . From this script file, I'm executing a sql file `getUserDetails.sql` . The sql file has one `SELECT` statement to get the user details like userid, username.

Now I want this output userid and username in the shell script from which I'm executing the sql file.

getUserDetails.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash          
echo Start Executing SQL commands
sqlplus <user>/<password> @file-with-sql-query.sql
```

From the `file-with-sql-query.sql` file I will get userid and usernme values. Now I want to store those values in variables in the shell script file for further use.

Please help me in this.

Comment: We can't help you write code to parse the output of `sqlplus...` if you don't show us the output of `sqlplus...`. Please [edit] your question to add that and state/show which parts of that you want saved in variables.

Comment: With the right command line arguments you can strip the headers and extraneous output, and read lines of output into an array of column values (they should be quoted). If there's only one line, that's often a good method. If there are multiple, you'd probably want to read over the lines in a loop. There are ways, depending on your data and your needs, but you didn't give us much on that.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have the output of the query, it is an important detail so we can give you a precise answer, so we asume two options.

- Saving the output of `sqlplus <user>/<password> @file-with-sql-query.sql` to a file.

```
sqlplus <user>/<password> @file-with-sql-query.sql > sql_output
cat sql_output
```

- Saving the output directly into a shell variable.

```
xSQLOUT="$(sqlplus <user>/<password> @file-with-sql-query.sql)"
echo $xSQLOUT
```